# Append Text After Selecting Option Second time jquery

Tags: jquery

Let Suppos I have Text As

```
<h5 class="product-title_main">INDIAN APPLE(KASHMIR)</h5>
```

And I Have Selct Box As

```
<select id="sources" class="">
    <option value="Available As Your Requirment">Available As Your Requirment</option>
    <option value="1170Kg">10Kg at 1170</option>
    <option value="3400Kg">30Kg at 3400</option>
    <option value="5700Kg">50Kg at 5700</option>
</select>
```

Now I wish to Change `H5` Tag Value on Change Of select box

*For Example*

if i select 2nd select box So  tag text changes to **"INDIAN APPLE(KASHMIR) 10Kg at 1170"**

*What I Tried*

```
<script>
        $("#sources").change(function(){
            var selectedval = $("#sources option:selected").val();
            var selectedtext = $("#sources option:selected").text();
            $(".dynamic_price").text("Rs. " + selectedval);
            $('.product-title_main').text($('.product-title_main').text() + ' ' + selectedtext);
        });
</script>
```

But problem is it append value every time. i do not want like that i want to show only selected value and remove old one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can initially set the `<h5>` text in a variable `var h5Text = $('.product-title_main').text();` and use that variable to set the text inside `<h5>` dynamically like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   
var h5Text = $('.product-title_main').text();
$("#sources").change(function(){
  var selectedval = $("#sources option:selected").val();
  var selectedtext = $("#sources option:selected").text();
  $(".dynamic_price").text("Rs. " + selectedval);
  $('.product-title_main').text(h5Text + ' ' + selectedtext);
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="product-title_main">INDIAN APPLE(KASHMIR)</h5>
<select id="sources" class="">
    <option value="Available As Your Requirment">Available As Your Requirment</option>
    <option value="1170Kg">10Kg at 1170</option>
    <option value="3400Kg">30Kg at 3400</option>
    <option value="5700Kg">50Kg at 5700</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the value of the h5 tag you just need to use `.html('your new value')`

Change to

```
$('.product-title_main').html(original_value + " " + selectedtext);
```

```js
var original_value = $('.product-title_main').html();
$("#sources").change(function() {
  var selectedval = $("#sources option:selected").val();
  var selectedtext = $("#sources option:selected").text();
  $(".dynamic_price").text("Rs. " + selectedval);
  $('.product-title_main').html(original_value + " " + selectedtext);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h5 class="product-title_main">INDIAN APPLE(KASHMIR)</h5>

<select id="sources" class="">
  <option value="Available As Your Requirment">Available As Your Requirment</option>
  <option value="1170Kg">10Kg at 1170</option>
  <option value="3400Kg">30Kg at 3400</option>
  <option value="5700Kg">50Kg at 5700</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Still It is appending when i select option second time

Comment: Ok I adjusted the Fiddle